# Number of times a dice must be thrown to get $6$ ten times before getting $5$ eight times

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Well, the title says it all. How are we supposed to start this?

I have calculated a recurrence relation for this $E(n, m)=\frac{4}{6}(1+E(n, m))+\frac{1}{6}(1+E(n-1, m))+\frac{1}{6}(1+E(n, m-1))$.

Is this the correct way and is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: To me the title does not say it all.  What does "get $6$ ten times before getting $5$ eight times" mean? Is this a conditional expectation?

Comment: Is it consecutive $6$ and consecutive $5$? If not, what happens if I get ten $6$ before eight $5$? Do I start over?

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I read the problem as follows:  consider all the sequences made by tossing a fair die.  Consider the subset consisting of those sequences in which ten $6's$ occur prior to eight $5's$...what is the expected length of a sequence in that subset?